# Programmatically access All Users Start Menu

Tags: c#, .net, setup-deployment, special-folders

Does anyone know how to programmatically access the "All Users" Startup Menu?

In XP, located here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

And in Windows 7, located here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Specifically, I've got a Setup and Deployment project, and I'd like to put a shortcut to the application in the Startup menu for all users so that the application is start whenever anyone logs in.

EDIT: [I'm pretty sure this is where Brian got his answer from.](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/580258-c%23-get-path-of-start-menu-programs-all-users/page__p__588773578&#entry588773578)

Comment: Credit goes to Brian R. Bondy; he answered the question as I phrased it.  I ended up creating a folder named "Startup" under "User's Programs Menu" (View > File System). And I relied on the user installing the program with "Install ... for yourself, or for anyone who uses this computer" set to "Everyone". If the user selected "Just me", then it would have only been placed in the Startup menu for that user. And I suppose I'm OK with that.  I suppose I *could* have copied a shortcut in a Custom Action using Brian's method...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no constant defined for the normal way of `Environment.GetFolderPath` for the all users start menu, but you can do  it this way by using the Win32 API `SHGetSpecialFolderPath`:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    static extern bool SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner,
       [Out] StringBuilder lpszPath, int nFolder, bool fCreate);
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_STARTMENU = 0x16;  // All Users\Start Menu

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(260);
        SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, path, CSIDL_COMMON_STARTMENU, false);
        string s = path.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I didn't have to use the Win32 API, but this does the job.

Comment: Very common to have to use the Win32 API from C# :)

Comment: @fre0n: If you don't want to use Win32 API you can use the MSI properties made for that purpose.

Comment: full references in [ShlObj.h](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/9b69fd26ac0c7d0b83d378dba01080e93349c2ed/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/ShlObj.h#L1113)

Answer (score 22):

In .NET 4 `CommonStartMenu` was added to the [`Environment.SpecialFolder` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx), so you can use:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu)
```

Comment: This is awesome, however, attempting to access that folder programmatically will give you "Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu' is denied."   so doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex By "access" you mean modify items in the folder? That will definitely require admin permissions and applies to all answers to this question not just this one.

Comment: In my case, I was simply trying to remove a shortcut to an app, and calling IO.Directory.GetFiles on that start menu path blew up with an Access Denied.   It would seem that in about half the cases, people would want modify access.  Read Only seems very limited usefulness.  So it's one thing to have a path to something, but another to be able to use it for anything.  I realize "using" the path wasn't really the question, but the next logical inference would include using it, and perhaps for modify.

Answer (score 4):

"All Users" resides in the ALLUSERSPROFILE environment variable:

```
C:\>dir "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu"
 Volume in drive C is awesome
 Volume Serial Number is 8C57-DB1A

 Directory of C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu

12/28/2009  10:27 PM    <DIR>          .
12/28/2009  10:27 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/28/2009  10:01 PM             1,566 Microsoft Update.lnk
02/23/2010  09:57 PM    <DIR>          Programs
12/28/2009  10:27 PM             1,563 Set Program Access and Defaults.lnk
12/28/2009  08:51 PM               398 Windows Catalog.lnk
12/28/2009  08:51 PM             1,507 Windows Update.lnk
               4 File(s)          5,034 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  64,214,460,416 bytes free
```

Comment: This may not work depending on the locale of the Windows installed.

Comment: It actually works on Windows 7, but it doesn't point to the Startup folder.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try!

```
string allUsers=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSPROFILE")+ "\\Start Menu\\Programs";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the startup folder using the appropriate MSI property (see [here](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q105378) for more details): `[StartupFolder`]

However, as typical for user-dependent MSI variables, this property points either to the user's startup folder or the all users' startup folder, depending on the value of the ALLUSERS property.

This means that when you install for "Everyone" (per-machine) you will get the folder

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
```

otherwise you will the per-user folder within the user's profile. This is by design and also makes sense, as a per-user installation will not have permission to write to the all users folder.

In your *Setup and Deployment* project, do the following to place files into the startup folder:

- open the *File System* view,
- right-click the folder tree and add a custom folder.
- under the properties of this folder, set *DefaultLocation* to `[StartupFolder]`
- add the content to the custom folder

Answer (score 0):

From C++, as for moment of writing this, Microsoft encourages to use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` with desired value of `KNOWNFOLDERID` enum. The value you need to use is `FOLDERID_CommonStartMenu`. In your case, the code would look like:

```
wchar_t * path = nullptr;
const auto result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_CommonStartMenu, 0, NULL, &path);
if (S_OK == result)
{
    // do what you want with path, f.ex. create string from it
    std::wstring pathAsString(path);
    // according to documentation, calling process is responsible for freeing this resource
    CoTaskMemFree(path);
}
```

Reference of `SHGetKnownFolderPath` is there:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx

Reference of all available values of enum `KNOWNFOLDERID` is there:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx

Info, that calling process is responsible for freeing resource, can be found in documentation of `SHGetKnownFolderPath` in part documenting `ppszPath` parameter.

Please note, that when it is executed from service, some values are not available (for example related to data of user, f.ex. `FOLDERID_Documents`). Moreover, if some values are not available if you are using different architecture (f.ex. value related to `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64` is not available on 32-bit operating system).

If somebody is willing to know where Microsoft encourages to use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` instead of other available functions, please read top of documentation of deprecated `SHGetFolderPath`.